# Disconnect a RAID 1

Tags: debian, raid

I currently have a setup of a 2 disks in RAID 1. How-ever I'd like to disconnect the raid and only run off one disk. Is this possible? Or will I have to reinstall the system?

The RAID is a soft-raid using Debians build in system.

Regards

Comment: No;  It would be possible if you were using a hardware RAID.

Comment: I'm not sure that's accurate. Couldn't you just fail one drive, reformat it, copy the data from the degraded RAID1, and be good to go?

Comment: The thing is i wish to disconenct the raid and only run on 1 drive forward. I need the second hard-drive for another purpose.